# Iterating over class properties using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

There is a ParsedTemplate class that it has over 300 property (typed Details and BlockDetails). The parsedTemplate object will be fill by a function. After filling this object I need a LINQ (or other way) to find is there any property like "body" or "img" where `IsExist=false` and `Priority="high"`.

```
public class Details
{
    public bool IsExist { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
}

public class BlockDetails : Details
{
    public string Block { get; set; }
}

public class ParsedTemplate
{
    public BlockDetails body { get; set; }
    public BlockDetails a { get; set; }
    public Details img { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is really easy to do with reflection, but I don't see how LINQ would be useful.  Why does everyone try to solve every problem with LINQ?

Comment: @cadrell0 because people tend to think LINQ is a silver bullet

Comment: @cadrell0 and all the strange syntax that does those laser stuff just HAS to be LINQ

Comment: @cadrell0 Please write a code with reflection

Comment: you actually dont event need reflection, if you care for the Details property only. what do you mean when you write "any property like "body" or "img""?

Comment: 300 Properties sounds likes a bad idea to begin with. Surely some form of collection/hierarchy/dictionary would represent it better (as you seem to be parsing HTML).

Comment: @HiTechMagic: Ha, good call. I just blindly answered the question without considering that it does, indeed, appear that the OP is parsing HTML...

Comment: If this ends up needing to parse multiple structures, I'd really suggest caching the reflection data.

Comment: @Ghooti Probably not the best to want people to just write the code for you.

Comment: Refactor this to use a dictionary.  If you have a class with 300 properties you're probably doing something wrong.  The only way I can see that is if they are all very unique.  In your case it looks like they are just a large collection of HTML tags. It's easier than reflection and if you're not comfortable with reflection enough yourself to do it, then don't, there are other options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to need to write your own method to make this appetizing. Fortunately, it doesn't need to be long. Something like:

```
static IEnumerable<Details> GetDetails(ParsedTemplate parsedTemplate)
{
    return from p in typeof(ParsedTemplate).GetProperties()
           where typeof(Details).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)
           select (Details)p.GetValue(parsedTemplate, null);
}
```

You could then, if you wanted to check if any property "exists" on a `ParsedTemplate` object, for example, use LINQ:

```
var existingDetails = from d in GetDetails(parsedTemplate)
                      where d.IsExist
                      select d;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really wanted to use linq while doing that, you could try something like that:

```
bool isMatching = (from prop in typeof(ParsedTemplate).GetProperties()
                   where typeof(Details).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)
                   let val = (Details)prop.GetValue(parsedTemplate, null) 
                   where val != null && !val.IsExist && val.Priority == "high"
                   select val).Any();
```

Works on my machine.

Or in extension method syntax:

```
isMatching = typeof(ParsedTemplate).GetProperties()
                 .Where(prop => typeof(Details).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
                 .Select(prop => (Details)prop.GetValue(parsedTemplate, null))
                 .Where(val => val != null && !val.IsExist && val.Priority == "high")
                 .Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use c# reflection. For example:

```
ParsedTemplate obj;
PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty("img");
Details value = (Details)(pi.GetValue(obj, null));
if(value.IsExist)
{
   //Do something
}
```

I haven't compile but i think it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ParsedTemplate tpl = null;
        // tpl initialization
        typeof(ParsedTemplate).GetProperties()
            .Where(p => new [] { "name", "img" }.Contains(p.Name))
            .Where(p => 
                {
                    Details d = (Details)p.GetValue(tpl, null) as Details;
                    return d != null && !d.IsExist && d.Priority == "high"
                });
```

Comment: While this does the same as Dan Tao's answer, it is not as reusable as his (basically too complex for the problem it is trying to solve *if you need to repeat this for any variations*).