# Join string properties of list of objects

Tags: vb.net

I've got list of `Contact` objects that among others, has a `mailaddress` string property. I would like to create a ";" delimited string from all these addresses. Is it possible to do this with a built-in function like the `Join(delimiter,array)` or the `Join (of ...)`, without iterating trough the list manually?

Comment: It's hard to help without code, check [mcve] also take a look at this as it explains how to iterate through the properties of a class [Iterate class property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033198/iterating-over-class-properties-using-linq) Or you can simply just `For each contact in the list MyStr = Mystr & Contact.mailddress & ";" Next` and then delete the last ";"

Comment: It would be an ugly solution, but you could use the `String.Join(Of T) method` provided you override the `ToString` method of the `Contacts` class to return the desired property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorta.

```
Dim str = string.Join(";"c, YourList.Select(function(c) c.mailaddress))
```

You don't have to use a foreach loop, but the list does have to be iterated.  LINQ can do that for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most compact solution. There's a typo I think, the `";"c` should be `";"`. At least this is how it works for me.

Comment: @vilmarci: in vb, a single char literal is created using that syntax.  So, not a typo, but unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, NO.

You will have to iterate through all the `Contacts`, adding the `mailaddress` properties to a `New List(Of String)`.

To get your delimited string, `YourList.ToArray().Join(",")`

Hope that helps.